# WCF RIA Services / ChangeSet Complete

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a business requirement that needs to be executed after all the WCF RIA services changes have been implemented on the server side, but before WCF RIA Services sends data back to the client.

I realize that I could easily add the logic on the client, after a save has been completed.  However, I would rather avoid the round-trip back to the server.

Is there an interception point for this on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this
http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/12/29/wcf-ria-services-domainservice-life-cycle-and-adding-transactions.aspx